# How to disable "To get future Google Chrome updates, you'll need Windows 10 or later" startup warning on portable Ungoogled Chromium?

Tags: chromium, portable-apps

To disable "To get future Google Chrome updates, you'll need Windows 10 or later" warning on Google Chrome, we know that it's by setting `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome "SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning" REG_DWORD` to 1.

But its said not to work for portable editions and for sure for Ungoogled Chromium portable editions.
There seems no online help on this.

`chrome://policy/`   with  "Show policies with no value set" checked shows the `SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning` option as not set, but there is no means to change it there. (the string is from chrome.dll)

How to get rid of this warning on Ungoogled Chromium portable?

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I assume after you set `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Google\Chrome\SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning` you performed a reboot?

Comment: @Ramhound : for google-chrome the mentioned solution works instantly (without reboot) - only the browser neds to be relaunched

Comment: @John : Windows 7SP1+ 32bit

Comment: Windows 7 is now so outdated you may have to live with message.  Try uninstalling it and installing and older version. I have an old version on my own Windows 7 VM . It doesn’t try update

Comment: @martinist, since Ubuntu 32-bit 18.04 still can be installed, give it a try from USB (without installing it). There are many alternatives, too: https://www.debugpoint.com/32-bit-linux-distributions/ rex mortuus est, vivat Linux.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik : "rex mortuus est, vivat Linux" (it's not subject related, but I like it).

Comment: @John : "outdated" is mostly a M$ policy, and unfortunately they make it technical reality as well. I personally will never go for Win10 and above as they present huges privacy concerns, just as smartphones (but this is an other subject).

Comment: @martinist OSes interact with the entire technology world and all the nefarious actors in it. It is not simply a whim of MS that a given OS is outdated. If you do not wish to use a modern Windows OS, it is far better to use an OS that meets your privacy needs while also being up to date and better able to deal with the current environment than the very old and truly and actually outdated Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After having made some registry tries, inspiring from the one that works for googled-chromium, it turns out that this works:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Chromium]
"SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning"=dword:00000001
```

So instead of "Google\Chrome" key, using just a "Chromium" key (after the name that appears in the "about" box).

Now **chrome://policy/** shows the **SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning** option set to true. So even a "portable" version checks the OS registry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Back here in 2023! Writing an update for anyone that still fields calls from relatives running older versions of Windows.

Run cmd.exe as administrator, if you can't find it...

- Open My Computer > C > Windows > System32 > cmd.exe
- Hold shift, then right click on cmd, run as administrator

Then copy this, right click in the cmd window, paste, enter.

```
reg add "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome" /v SuppressUnsupportedOSWarning /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```